# Ошибка при подключении к базе MySQL через сервер на NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, xampp

База открыта локально на сервере XAMPP. Пытаюсь подключится к базе при помощи данного NodeJS кода:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8080,
    path: 'phpmyadmin',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'users'
});

connection.connect(err => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('NOT CONNECTED');
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    } else {
        console.log('Connected');
    }
});

connection.end();
```

Но возникает такая ошибка:

```
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.     
fatal: true, 
code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'
```

Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, если Вы еще не настраивали Ваш MySQL - потому что изначально он не даёт руту право удаленного подключения.

Эту проблему можно решить двояко:

или даём руту право удаленного подключения из консоли mysql, примерно так:

```
    mysql -u root
    GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'192.168.0.103' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

    GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'%'  WITH GRANT OPTION;

    GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'0.0.0.0' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Но это - ОЧЕНЬ ПЛОХОЙ СПОСОБ, не рекомендуемый на практике.

Лучше сделать отдельного пользователя и ему дать право удаленного подключения, примерно так:

```
    /* Посмотреть список пользователей: */
    SELECT Host, USER, plugin from mysql.user;

    /* Создание нового newuser с паролем password  */

    CREATE USER 'newuser'@'109.252.65.30' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

    grant all privileges on *.* to 'newuser'@'109.252.65.30';

    ALTER USER 'newuser'@'109.252.65.30' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Там в скрипте еще IP остался `109.252.65.30`, замените его на тот, с которого будет подключаться нода. Возможно, проканает `0.0.0.0` или `%` в качестве "любого IP" - но тут уже  не уверен, попробуйте. Начать лучше с одного конкретного IP.

Надеюсь, поможет